# Perl API Net::Google::Spreadsheets, how to rename worksheet and spreadsheet?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I got the answer how to find worksheet title.
Now I would like to ask for your help to explain me how to rename worksheet or spreadsheet. CPAN documentation doesn't have any suggestion.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that is currently not possible. It seems like you can neither rename, move or create a new spreadsheet. You can only operate on existing spreadsheets. It's possible to change worksheets within existing spreadsheets though.

Comment: Thanks. That is bad, actually. My idea was to keep only one worksheet inside of shared spreadsheet. And as long as we can't delete the last worksheet, I thought I would be able to rename existing one, then create new one and fill it with data, then delete first one. Now the only solution is to create temporary, then delete existing, then create and fill up new one, and then delete temporary. = Wasting time.

Comment: I have not seen a method to make a new one, so how would that work programatically? You can of course check the source code of that module, and the API description and write a patch. The author has the github linked on metacpan.

Comment: To add new worksheet you need:
`my $new_worksheet = $spreadsheet->add_worksheet(
    {
        title => 'New_Worksheet-2',
        row_count => 10,
        col_count => 15,
    }
  );`

Comment: But that says _worksheet_. I thought a worksheet is a page, and a _spreadsheet_ is a document. Maybe that wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: You cant add the data to spreadsheet. But you can do it into worksheet. That is why I do not really care about spreadsheet. You are actually right - there is no example how to create spreadsheet, only how to delete one.

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible without write a patch. But you can create a new worksheet and delete the old worksheet.

```
# delete the worksheet
$worksheet->delete;
```